# CMake: How to tell where transitive dependency is coming from?

Tags: cmake

I'm in the process of rewriting a legacy CMake setup to use modern features like automatic dependency propagation.  (i.e. using things like `target_include_directories(<target> PUBLIC <dir>)` instead of `include_directories(<dir>)`.)  Currently, we manually handle all project dependency information by setting a bunch of global directory properties.

In my testing, I've found a few examples where a target in the new build will link to a library that the old build would not.  I'm not linking to it explicitly, so I know this is coming from the target's dependencies, but in order to find which one(s) I have to recursively look through all of the project's `CMakeLists.txt`s, following up the dependency hierarchy until I find one that pulls in the library in question.  We have dozens of libraries so this is not a trivial process.

**Does CMake provide any way to see, for each target, which of its dependencies were added explicitly, and which ones were propagated through transitive dependencies?**

It looks like the [`--graphviz`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Graphviz) output *does* show this distinction, so clearly CMake knows the context internally.  However, I'd like to write a `tree`-like script to show dependency information on the command line, and parsing Graphviz files sounds like both a nightmare and a hack.

As far as I can tell, [`cmake-file-api`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html) does *not* include this information.  I thought the [`codemodel/target/dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html#codemodel-version-2-target-object) field might work, but it lists both local and transitive dependencies mixed together.  And the `backtrace` field of each dependency only ties back to the `add_executable`/`add_library` call for the current target.

Comment: How doesn't `--graphiz` option not answer your question? Why parsing dot files feels like a nightmare? Dot files is the simplest, common and flexible way to human-readable represent connected points. With `gvpr` utility you can do anything with them in awk-ish style, and you can import them in other languages. Why is a dot file, that literally represents a tree-like structure of dependencies between targets, not a "way to see" that what you ask for?

Comment: @KamilCuk Fair enough.  I think I was hoping for a more standardized format like JSON that I could read without installing additional packages and without writing my own parser.  I assumed that the dependency graph would be available in multiple formats (I still need to experiment with the [CMake server API](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-server.7.html), for example).  But if dotfiles are the easiest (or only) way to get that information, that's fine.

Comment: I wouldn't stake too many bets on Graphviz showing these differently. The code that tells it apart [is linked here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmLinkItemGraphVisitor.cxx#L61), it's not very sophisticated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse `dot` file generated by `graphviz` and extract details which you want. Below is sample python script to do that.

```
import pydot
import sys

graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_file(sys.argv[1])
result = {}

for g in graph:
    # print(g)
    for node in g.get_node_list():
        if node.get("label") != None:
            result[node.get("label")] = []

    for edge in g.get_edges():
        result[g.get_node(edge.get_source())[0].get("label")].append(g.get_node(edge.get_destination())[0].get("label"))

for r in result:
    print(r+":"+",".join(result[r]))
```

You can also add this script to run from cmake as custom target, so you can call it from you build system. You can find sample cmake project [here](https://github.com/manthanrtilva/stackoverflow/tree/master/59220908)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'll have to look into `pydot`.